# joomla menu manager custom component

Tags: joomla

I have a custom component and would like to create backend menu items.

I've created meatada.xml and *.xml files in tmpl dirs.

The problems is the strycture of the link is always option=my_component&view=some_view&layout=some

and i have structure like c=controller&task=add

how to change default link in joomla backend menu manager?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to get what you need by setting menu parameters, but in general you will make menu items based on the view you want to display. If you follow Joomla's MVC structure this works well because the view will have a corresponding controller. Take a look at the component parameters documentation to see if it fits your need - [Component parameters](http://docs.joomla.org/Component_parameters)